# How to specify the Visual Studio version of MSBuild for execute the validation of Architecture in .Net Solution TFS 2013

Tags: msbuild

I have defined an MSbuild project for build a .Net Solution developed with VS 2015 Enterprise. The Tfs Build Server is TFS 2013, i have installed on the server the VS 2015 Enterprise. I specified the MSBuild version i want to use on the Build process setting on the Build definition the parameters: /tv:14.0 and /p:ValidateArchitecture=true on the following order:

MSBuild Arguments:  /p:ValidateArchitecture=true /tv:14.0

I have Modeling project on my solution that i want to validate on Build time at TFS Build process. The fact is that when the validation process start it fails, and i see that the Visual Studio version is used for that is v11.0 instead of v14.0 . How can i force TFS to use the v14.0 for validation modeling project at Build process:

Here you can see the Build log of the process:

```
ValidateArchitecture_GenerateDgmlForLayers:
Processing      
E:\...Project Source\XXXPPP\Arch.layerdiagram...
-query obj\Release\Arch.layerdiagram.dgql -output     
obj\Release\Arch.layerdiagram.dgml -format SimplifiedDgml -uiculture     
en-US -exceptions 
C:\Program Files   
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ **v11.0** \ArchitectureTools\
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.LayerDesigner.targets(148,5): error  
MSB4018: The "GraphCmd" task failed unexpectedly.   
[Drive:\Comp\3\Project Source\XXXPPP\Arch.modelproj]
```

As you can see, the validation process is using **v11.0** version, i have in the MSBuild TFS Path the **v14.0**, how to use this last version for validation process??.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the "GraphCmd" task a custom build activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using the old build template not the default template for TFS 2013. You could edit your build process template and set the **ToolPath** property of the MSBuild activity to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin". For more details, you could refer to this blog: [Update MSBuild Toolpath in TFS build process template](https://medium.com/into-alm/update-msbuild-toolpath-in-tfs-build-process-template-59f00a542ac9)

If you don't find the ToolPath property and the MSBuild activity but an activity named "Run MSBuild", find the MSBuild activity and [replace the "RunMSBuild](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5cdee11a-5348-4f45-be2e-f6f8c4d8a2d5/control-msbuild-version-msbuildtoolspath-for-build-definition?forum=tfsgeneral) activity". Then set the Toolpath property.

Here are some other that may help you: [TFSBuild 2013 unable to change msbuild version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607222/tfsbuild-2013-unable-to-change-msbuild-version)

[Update Build Controller/Agents to build C# 6 /.NET 4.6 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654804/update-build-controller-agents-to-build-c-sharp-6-net-4-6-application)