# Question - Why TFS is taking Msbuild 10.0 Instead of Version 14.0?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, .net-framework-version

Configured Task in TFS as Visual Studio Build task and configred Version to the Visual Studio 2015.
Still this is giving me an error -

"**##[warning]Visual Studio version '14.0' not found. Falling back to version '10.0'.**"

I managed it to use with MSBuild task by giving manual path of msbuild 14.0.
but,
My Question is why build agent is taking version 10.0 from VS build task?

I found a link(reference link -[TFSBuild 2013 unable to change msbuild version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607222/tfsbuild-2013-unable-to-change-msbuild-version) ) says It can be possible by playing with Registry. This is like Fix of this problem..How to configure msbuild 14.0 as my default builder?

Comment: This issue be caused by the same reason, you can delete it or approval the close suggestion. If you have other question, you can open a new thread or update your question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes @LeoLiu-MSFT.. That is why I am finding now the way to  Run MSBuild 14.0 from the .net framework and not from Visual Studio. Installed .net framework 4.6.1 also though this is taking MSbuild 10.0 of .net framework 4.0.3xx.