# Building a solution containing .net standard 2.0 project in team foundation server 2012 server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution in visual studio 2017. This solution contains a project in .Net Standard 2.0. I have team foundation server 2012. I have configured a build controller and build agent on the team foundation server. I have configured a build for continuous integration. The build definition used to work fine before adding the .NET Standard 2.0 project. But now the build gives following error while compiling the solution

> The attribute "Version" in element  is unrecognized.

I have tried the following but nothing has worked so far

1. Installed Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 on the team foundation server as mentioned in this blog https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2017/11/15/building-net-core-and-net-standard-projects-in-tfs-2015/
2. Changed the msbuild.exe path in the registry as mentiond here[TFSBuild 2013 unable to change msbuild version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607222/tfsbuild-2013-unable-to-change-msbuild-version). I have set it to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin

But it does not work. Now I wonder whether team foundation 2012 build server is compatible at all with Visual Studio 2017 or am I missing something ?

Comment: It's possible but it's probably going to require messing around with the build process template XAML and be a big pain. Have you considered upgrading to a modern version of TFS? Your organization is 7 years behind, which is an eternity in the software world.

Comment: Hi friend, have you tried run the msbuild command in local machine. Without TFS, just run the msbuild tool manually to run the solution, what's the result? If same issue persists, a screenshot about the error message could be better.